# how to modify ~/.inputrc for brackets autocompletion in bash vi mode?

Tags: bash, autocomplete, readline

With emacs mode the following works:

```
"(": "\C-v()\e[D"
```

But if you add the following at the beginning:

```
set editing-mode vi
```

it does not work anymore. Any solutions?

Also, where can I find a good reference for editing inputrc file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following into ~/.inputrc solves the problem:

```
set editing-mode vi
set keymap vi-insert
"\C-b": backward-char
"(": "\C-v()\C-b"
"[": "\C-v[]\C-b"
"{": "\C-v{}\C-b"
"\"": "\C-v\"\C-v\"\C-b"
"\047": "\C-v\047\C-v\047\C-b"
```

or in ~/.bashrc:

```
set -o vi
bind -m vi-insert '"(" "\C-v()\ei"'
bind -m vi-insert '"[" "\C-v[]\ei"'
bind -m vi-insert '"{" "\C-v{}\ei"'
bind -m vi-insert '"\"" "\C-v\"\C-v\"\ei"'
bind -m vi-insert '"\047" "\C-v\047\C-v\047\ei"'
```